# Remove string between two chars

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this String

> ```
> test this a [^architecture.jpg] 
> lorem epsum
> lorem epsum
> [^rct.png]
> lorem epsum
> ```

I need to remove string between [^ and ]

to get something like

```
test this a 
lorem epsum
lorem epsum
lorem epsum
```

I tried this regex in JAVA

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^.*?]", "");
```

But it doesn't worked

Would you have any ideas please ?

Best regards

Comment: `[`, `]` and `^` are [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), you need to escape them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you're not escaping these characters: `[]^`, so they're being treated as special characters in the regex. Basically, right now it's replacing any character which is not `.`, `*`, or `?`, which just leaves you with the two periods. Just add `\\` before each of them to escape them, and it will work like you want.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[\\^.*?\\]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks guy you are awsome

Answer (score 2):

you regex is not correct

use something like

```
String str = "test this a [^architecture.jpg]" + "lorem epsum" + "lorem epsum" + "[^rct.png]" + "lorem epsum";
String foo = "(?s)\\[\\^.+?\\]";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(foo, ""));
```

the output is:

> test this a lorem epsumlorem epsumlorem epsum

Answer (score 1):

just add \\ and string will look like

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[\\^.*?\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

`^`, `[` and `]` are **special characters** that you need to escape first that is why it doesn't work which can be done by prefixing each special character with `\\`.

If you want to remove everything between `[^` and `]` you can use `\\[\\^[^]]*\\]` as regular expression defining a character sequence:

1. Starting with `[^`,
2. Containing a sequence of `0` or more of any characters except `]`,
3. Then `]`:

The corresponding code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[\\^[^]]*\\]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks guys you are awsome